# Unable to get songs according to album and artists

Tags: android, mediastore, audio-player, android-music-player

I want to show songs according to artists and albums but i am unable to query for it.

```
 String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS };
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting null in your resolver.query, you do not need to assign variables selection and SelectionArgs.

On the face of it I can not see anything wrong but you have not listed any errors or what the outcome actually is.

However this is how I do it:

```
      public Cursor getAlbums(Context context) {
    String[] dataColumns;
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    dataColumns = new String[]{
            BaseColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
            MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.FIRST_YEAR,
            MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ARTIST};
    String sort_order = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM + " ASC";
    Cursor acursor = resolver.query
            (MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    dataColumns,
                    null, null,
                    sort_order);
    return acursor;
}
```